# setting custom background overrides ListView customization

Tags: android

I've modified a list view to have a different selection color and item backgrounds. Things are working perfectly until I set a custom color on the application or activity background (solid color, png, gradient). I tried using cache color hint also, but it does not seem to work.

I've been on google pretty much the whole of yesterday and haven't found an answer. The closest I've come is this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/24f8f2a4f9beae88):

The gentleman seems to say that this is as designed. If it is I'd like to hear how I could change the background color of the entire list view (I'm talking about the area in the list view that may be empty).

If you want to look at some code you will find it [here](http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/listview-selector-and-custom-background/).

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking, so let me explain how all the items that you are playing with work together, and perhaps your answer will be in there somewhere.  There are three distinct visual elements that you have described in your question:

1. A list item's background
2. The list selector
3. The overall ListView's background

By default, they will be drawn in that hierarchy, meaning (1) is drawn on top of (2), (2) is drawn on top of (3), and so on.  On a ListView with no customization, items 2 & 3 are transparent and the selector is a drawable with multiple states.  Because of this, any custom colors you apply to the Activity or any View beneath the ListView is going to show through, due to the transparency.

If you look at the order in which these things are drawn, you can start to see how customizing one element may cover up any customization done to another element.  For example, if you set an opaque background on each item of the list, and `listSelector` attribute the list has will be completely covered up (unless `drawSelectorOnTop` is set...which is why when developer do that they provided a drawable with states as the background item).

ListView is just another view, and you may set its `background` attribute directly if you wanted to provide a background to the entire ListView and hide the Views displaying underneath it.  Again, if you were to set a custom list item background, this would not be visible except for areas where the ListView is large enough to display all its elements and there is extra space below them.

The job of `cacheColorHint` is to optimize scrolling performance by telling each list item to draw itself with a solid color background (while scrolling) instead of being transparent.  If you set a solid color background on ListView or the Activity beneath, this value should be set to the same color.  If your background is a gradient or image, you cannot use this optimization and it should be set to transparent (i.e. #0000)

Hope that Helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Devenwired for taking the time. I understand the order the listview is rendered is: _background_, _seperators_, _selector_ and finally the _list items_. I've taken care to make my item backgrounds and selector to be transparent accordingly. Now I have a different problem - every thing is working as expected, my custom background renders as i want them to. However, I do not have the cache color hint set. So technically, from what I've read things should not be working. I'm a little confused.